# using function to print two variables

Tags: c

The function seems not work, what is the correct form when you `print variable(string)` in a function?

```
void f1(char ara, char arb)
{
    printf("Acronym found:\n       %s - %s\n", ara, arb);

}


int main(void)
{
    char  arc[20],ar1[] = "AFAIK",ard1[] = "as far as I know";

printf("Welcome to the internet help system\nEnter \"quit\" to exit the program\n");
do
{
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", &arc);

    if (strcmp(arc, ar1) == 0)
        f1(ar1, ard1);

.......
```

Comment: This `void f1(char ara, char arb)` is wrong, you are passing strings, not chars.

Comment: i think there is no return value so i use void, i think char is how you define a string

Comment: Change void `f1(char ara, char arb)` for `void f1(char *ara, char *arb)`.

Comment: thank you, it works now although i dont know why

Comment: Normally it would be a char* not just a single char.  You we passing an array but the function definition is for single char.  What is the error message or what is the output with it not working.

Comment: Well char is a single character and char* is pointer to the char array. Strings are null terminated char arrays.

Answer (score 1):

just change the type of the arguments in f1 into pointer variable.

void f1(char *ara, char *arb)

because while giving char it will take only one character as it has only one byte to store the character.

when you convert it into character pointer, it will have 4 bytes to store the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
void f1(char *ara, char *arb)
{
printf("Acronym found:\n       %s - %s\n", ara, arb);

}
(or)

void f1(char ara[], char arb[])
  {
printf("Acronym found:\n       %s - %s\n", ara, arb);

 }
```

use this type of argument when get a string from another function.